# How to allow Forward Slash (/) in JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, telerik-grid

In my RadGrid I am using Filter for DATE Column. Date format is like this 16/12/1990. Filter textbox should allow only Numbers and `/`. How to write JavaScript function to do this?

```
function CharacterCheckDate(text, e)
{
    var regx, flg;
    regx = /[^0-9/'' ]/
    flg = regx.test(text.value);
    if (flg)
    {
        var val = text.value;
        val = val.substr(0, (val.length) - 1)
        text.value = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working in this regex?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to worry about `/` in character class, ([thanks Robin for pointing that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357669/how-to-allow-forward-slash-in-javascript-regex/23357695?noredirect=1#comment35775542_23357695)). For example,

```
console.log(/[^\d/]/.test("/"));
# false
console.log(/[^\d/]/.test("a"));
# true
```

If you are really in doubt, simply escape it with backslash, like this

```
regx = /[^0-9\/'' ]/
```

Also, you don't need to specify `'` twice, once is enough.

```
regx = /[^0-9\/' ]/
```

Instead of using numbers explicitly, you can use `\d` character class, like this

```
regx = /[^\d\/' ]/
```

So, you could have written your RegEx, like this

```
regx = /[^\d/' ]/
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to escape it inside a character class, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226731/escape-forward-slash-in-jscript-regexp-range

Comment: @Robin Thanks man :) Included an example in the answer now. Please check.

Comment: You're welcome :) I agree with your answer but now I don't see how the regex is different from the one OP used (except cleaner). I'm not familiar with telerik-grid but OP's issue (if he has one?) might be in the rest of the code.